# Two calculators in menu

Tags: gnome

My question is simple. I have two identical 'gnome-calculator' shortcuts in my apps menu. If I go to `/usr/share/applications/`, I see only one shortcut there. In that directory I also see two identical 'Archive Manager' shortcuts, three identical 'Files' shortcuts etc. What should I do?

Comment: Have you checked your user folder? `ls ~/.local/share/applications/`

Comment: My `~/.local/share/applications/` directory is almost empty. There are only wine folder and 'mimeinfo.cache' file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I went to 'Ubuntu Software' and uninstalled 'Gnome Calculator'. Now it doesn't say this standalone package is installed, and one of the menu shortcuts disappeared. But the other one is still there and I can use it.

I guess, 'gnome-calculator' was included by both standalone package and Gnome stack itself... Although it feels weird.

Comment: `gnome-calculato` exists as a deb-package and also as a snap-package, probably both had been installed in your system.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same "problem".  I removed one using Ubuntu Software and then used the Synaptic Package Manager to successfully remove the other.  I then re-installed Calculator using Ubuntu Software.  I have no idea why but it worked but I now have one calculator when displaying using Show Applications.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Calculator, grey colored full calculator, is the one provided by Ubuntu Bionic.
The other one, with +-= logo, is provided by Ubuntu partner Canonical. You can uninstall this one.
You can check for yourself by right-clicking shortcut then Show Details.